# Android NFC RF Time

Tags: android, tags, smartcard, nfc

I work on Android 2.3.3 with Nexus S.
I try to read smart cards ISO14443 B type.

I can read and/or write on the cards without any problem. But I am using a card which doesn't respect the ISO timing. When you use the ISO cards, the timing is nearly 5 or 7ms but I need to increase this timing.

I need of your help at this point. How can I increase the timing? I don't know how to do it at the low level.

Do you have any solution?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The nfc.technology IsoDep has a function to extend the default time-out value.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html

Comment: Thank you for your response but we don't talk about the same thing. I mean that the timeout in the IsoDep is to make bigger the time communication with the tag. My problem is :"I can't detect the tag when I hang over the card to the phone". The timing about which I talk must be in the low level. The configuration of this timing isn't documented.